# How to get html only from returned object vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, contentful

I have a vue project that needs to return data from a rich text field in Contentful.  The data is returned as an object, is there a way to render this data using the v-html directive?  At present I am able to render the html however it's wrapped in brackets, pictured below.

[image]

Code

```
  <div 
            v-if="testRich"

            class="mb4 testRich"

            v-html="testRich"
  />
```

Comment: `testRich.content[0].content[0].value` if you want the value

Comment: @depperm, Awesome, I knew it was something simple I was missing.  You can add that as the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: added to the bottom of my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use filters, if you actually want the whole object

```
Vue.filter('jsonPretty', (value)=>{
  return JSON.stringify(value,null,4)
})
```

and then usage:

```
<div>{{testRich | jsonPretty}}</div>
```

If you just want the value you need to reference it correctly:

```
v-html="testRich.content[0].content[0].value"
```